# express 4.0.0 generates deprecated dependencies and vulnerabilities

Tags: node.js, express

Having installed all the default versions from the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS repos:

```
nvm 0.35.0
node v10.16.3
npm 6.9.0
express 4.0.0
```

All the following commands (provided in the [express starter tutorial](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) and several StackOverflow questions and blogs)

```
express app --view=pug
express --view pug
express --pug
```

generate `package.json` like so:

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodejs ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.0.0",
    "static-favicon": "~1.0.0",
    "morgan": "~1.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.0.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "debug": "~0.7.4",
    "jade": "~1.3.0"
  }
}
```

Running `npm install` on that will, of course, produce depreciation warning for `jade` and also report a critical vulnerability for `constantinople@2.0.1`.

Not a good start, huh?

**Question**: How to get a working and current kickstart with express-generator (or anyhow else)?

Answer (score 6):

- Please use `npx express-generator` to get the latest version of express.
- In package.json remove Jade
- Install Pug (Jade has been renamed to pug) `npm install pug`
- Run `npm install` again
- In app.js changes `app.set('view engine', 'jade');` to `app.set('view engine', 'pug');`
- In **views** folder rename any jade file to pug. Ex: index.jade -> index.pug
- Run `npm audit` to check for any vulnerabilities again

Comment: This still generated critical security vulnerabilities for me. The problems seems to lie with the verions of constantinople that pug depends on. Running npm update constantinople --depth 4 fix that for me. Now I'm off to the races.

Comment: Thank you; This helped. It may have been because I didn't remove jade from package.json initially, but I still had to remove jade by running :npm remove jade

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upgrade package.json dependencies to the latest version, follow these steps -

1. Run npx express-generator --view=ejs my-app (you can change view to pug/handlebars if you want)
2. cd my-app, open in VS Code
3. Run npx npm-check-updates -u
4. Run npm install